# How do i check a list has distinct objects(is a set?) or not Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function in scheme which is checking a list is a set or not.

In C algorithm would be like this:

```
int count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) { 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
            //return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
(define set? (lambda (lst)

))
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the [racket] tag, so I'm going to assume that you're using Racket. You can use the library function [check-duplicates](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=remove-duplicates#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._check-duplicates%29%29) to check for duplicate elements. You can use [remove-duplicates](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=remove-duplicates#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know how you would do this if, for instance, the language didn't already have a set datatype (which Racket does) and a bunch of tools to deal with sets, including dealing with lists as sets.  So lets reinvent things that already exist, starting with a function which tells you if something occurs in a list (in real life this is a bunch of functions with names like `member`):

```
(define (occurs? e l (test? eqv?))
  ;; does e occur in l, testing with test?
  (cond [(null? l)
         ;; empty lists have no members
         #f]
        [(test? e (first l))
         ;; if e is the first element of l then it's in l
         #t]
        [else
         ;; if e is in the rest of l it's in l
         (occurs? e (rest l) test?)]))
```

And now you can answer the question as to whether a list is a set.  A list is a set if:

- it is the empty list;
- the first element of the list does not occur in the rest of the list, *and* the rest of the list is a set.

And this specification can be turned directly into code:

```
(define (list-set? l (test? eqv?))
  ;; is l a set?
  (if (null? l)
      ;; the empty list is a set
      #t
      ;; otherwise it is a set if ...
      (and
       ;; .. the first element of it does not occur in the rest of it ...
       (not (occurs? (first l) (rest l) test?))
       ;; ... and the rest of it is a set
       (list-set? (rest l) test?))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is having two cursors. `i` that starts at the beginning and goes towards next to last element and for each of those you have `j` that starts one next to `i` and goes to the end.

Here is how to make a loop:

```
(let name ((var 0) (var2 5))
  (if (> var var2)
      var
      (name (+ (* 2 var) 1) (+ var2 1))))
```

Since we are talking about lists here and lists are chains of `cons` instead of having indexes you just use the bindings to the individual `cons` for iteration:

```
(define test '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
(let find-half ((hare test) (tortoise test))
  (if (or (null? hare)
          (null? (cdr hare)))
      tortoise
      (find-half (cddr hare) (cdr tortoise))))
```

So what is the named `let`? It's a recursive function. The above is the same as:

```
(define test '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
(define (find-half hare tortoise)
  (if (or (null? hare)
          (null? (cdr hare)))
      tortoise
      (find-half (cddr hare) (cdr tortoise))))
(find-half test test)
```

It might be easier if you could write your C solution with recursion? Eg.

```c
int fori (int i) {
  return i >= count - 1 ||
         forj(i, i+1) && fori(i+1); 
}

int forj (int i, int j) {
  return j >= count || 
        array[i] == array[j] && forj(i, j+1);
}

int result = fori(0);
```

Comment: using `count` as the largest valid array index suggests the smallest valid array index is 1.

Comment: @WillNess good catch. I wanted the inverse of `i < count` and that is of course `i >= count` :)